# Bound function does not have prototype

Tags: javascript

From [***ecma-262 spec***](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)

> Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind do not have a
>   prototype property or the [[Code]], [[FormalParameters]], and
>   [[Scope]] internal properties.

It sounds like i am not able to do something like that (simple example)

```
const persone = {
  name: 'Hello World',
  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
};

const cat = {
  name: 'Cat'
}

const dog = {
  name: 'Dog'
}

console.log(persone.getName.bind(cat).bind(dog)()) // Cat
```

Why is it restricted? Are there any pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

its because bind wraps your function, inserting this. wrapping again then doesn't work.

its like this:

```
const persone = {
  name: 'Hello World',
  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
};

const cat = {
  name: 'Cat'
}

const dog = {
  name: 'Dog'
}
//its like doing this:
var methodNoThis = personne.getName;
var methodCatThis = function(){ return methodNoThis.apply(cat);
var methodDogOnCatThis = function(){ return methodCatThis.apply(dog);
```

### Documentation

Its also stated on [Mozzila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

The bind() function creates a new bound function (BF). A BF is an exotic function object (term from ECMAScript 2015)  that wraps the original function object. Calling a BF generally results in the execution of its wrapped function.

Comment: Thanks, but i know how to avoid it. The question is, Why is it restricted?

Comment: Probaby for anyone making this stupid mistake? wrapping the method again with this will have **no** effect and can only be a mistake/bug by the developer